# Docker compose stopped working - Windows Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently working on building various media services and everything was running fine up until today.

Now whenever I create a compose file and try to bring it up with the
docker compose up -d command I get the following error:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not string

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.keyValueIndexer({0x24c2140?, 0xc0003c00f0?}, {0xc00058cdab?, 0x1?})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/override/uncity.go:111 +0x79
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.enforceUnicity({0x237f460?, 0xc00061bed8?}, {0xc0002d0720, 0x1d})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/override/uncity.go:92 +0x415
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.enforceUnicity({0x24c2140?, 0xc0003046f0?}, {0xc0006155f0, 0x11})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/override/uncity.go:79 +0x1b3
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.enforceUnicity({0x24c2140?, 0xc000606330?}, {0x287e766, 0x8})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/override/uncity.go:79 +0x1b3
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.enforceUnicity({0x24c2140?, 0xc0004f1290?}, {0x0, 0x0})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/override/uncity.go:79 +0x1b3
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.EnforceUnicity(0x0?)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/override/uncity.go:68 +0x46
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/loader.loadYamlModel.func1({0x24c2140?, 0xc0004f1a10?}, {0xc0006903e8, 0x1, 0x1})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/loader/loader.go:385 +0x3e5
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/loader.loadYamlModel({0x2bf5cc0?, 0xc0000ac370}, {{0x0, 0x0}, {0xc000602bb0, 0x9}, {0xc000606930, 0x1, 0x1}, 0xc000606660}, ...)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/loader/loader.go:412 +0x8ff
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/loader.load({0x2bf5cc0, 0xc0000ac370}, {{0x0, 0x0}, {0xc000602bb0, 0x9}, {0xc000606930, 0x1, 0x1}, 0xc000606660}, ...)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/loader/loader.go:471 +0x38e
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/loader.LoadWithContext({0x2bf5cc0, 0xc0000ac370}, {{0x0, 0x0}, {0xc000602bb0, 0x9}, {0xc000606930, 0x1, 0x1}, 0xc000606660}, ...)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/loader/loader.go:322 +0x46f
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/cli.ProjectFromOptions(0xc000604280)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.7/cli/options.go:458 +0x612
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.(*ProjectOptions).ToProject(0xc000414dc0, {0x2bf5cc0?, 0xc0000ac370}, {0x2c090a0, 0xc000011200}, {0xc00058a0f0, 0x0, 0x1}, {0xc000453830, 0x2, ...})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:246 +0x608
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.upCommand.(*ProjectOptions).WithServices.func4({0x2bf5cc0, 0xc0000ac370}, {0xc00058a0f0, 0x0, 0x1})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:146 +0xf9
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.upCommand.(*ProjectOptions).WithServices.Adapt.func6({0x2bf5cc0?, 0xc0000ac370?}, 0x2?, {0xc00058a0f0?, 0x0?, 0x0?})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:109 +0x30
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.upCommand.(*ProjectOptions).WithServices.Adapt.AdaptCmd.func7(0x0?, {0xc00058a0f0, 0x0, 0x1})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:88 +0x14e
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/cmdtrace.Setup.wrapRunE.func2(0xc000011300?, {0xc00058a0f0?, 0x0?, 0x1?})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/cmdtrace/cmd_span.go:84 +0x65
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc0003ff800, {0xc0004f0440, 0x1, 0x1})
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:983 +0xabc
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc0004ee900)
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1115 +0x3ff
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1039
github.com/docker/cli/cli-plugins/plugin.RunPlugin(0x1fd1b650598?, 0xc0003ff500, {{0x287995d, 0x5}, {0x288358b, 0xb}, {0x2bd0b40, 0x11}, {0x0, 0x0}, ...})
        github.com/docker/cli@v25.0.3+incompatible/cli-plugins/plugin/plugin.go:64 +0x10e
github.com/docker/cli/cli-plugins/plugin.Run(0x29b8f40, {{0x287995d, 0x5}, {0x288358b, 0xb}, {0x2bd0b40, 0x11}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, ...}})
        github.com/docker/cli@v25.0.3+incompatible/cli-plugins/plugin/plugin.go:77 +0xe5
main.pluginMain()
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/main.go:37 +0xa5
main.main()
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/main.go:94 +0x19c
```

Every compose file does this now, all of which were previously working just fine.

I'm on the latest version of docker desktop v.4.28.0 and docker compose v is v2.24.6-desktop.1.  I even tried docker compose standalone v2.25.0.

Any ideas?

I've tried recreating all the compose file.  I've tried reinstalling docker desktop. I've tried downgrading the version.  I've tried rebooting the client, the pc.